# Shuffling Array in the same way, according to number

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, shuffle

I am running a quiz making website.  I wish to show the answers to a question to a user in a shuffled order.

I'm trying to **avoid** storing the order that answers were presented to the user, if I were to shuffle them randomly.

I want to shuffle the answers predictably, **so that I can repeat the shuffle in the same way later** (when displaying results).

I've thought that I could shuffle the list of answers by a certain number (either using the number within the sort, or having multiple types of sorts identifiable by an ID number.  **This way I can simply store the number that they were shuffled by and recall that number to reshuffle them again to the same order.**

Here's the skeleton of what I have so far, but I don't have any logic to put the answers back in the $shuffled_array in the shuffled order.

```
<?php

function SortQuestions($answers, $sort_id)
{
    // Blank array for newly shuffled answer order
    $shuffled_answers = array();

    // Get the number of answers to sort
    $answer_count = count($questions);

    // Loop through each answer and put them into the array by the $sort_id
    foreach ($answers AS $answer_id => $answer)
    {
        // Logic here for sorting answers, by the $sort_id

        // Putting the result in to $shuffled_answers
    }

    // Return the shuffled answers
    return $shuffled_answers;
}


// Define an array of answers and their ID numbers as the key
$answers = array("1" => "A1", "2" => "A2", "3" => "A3", "4" => "A4", "5" => "A5");

// Do the sort by the number 5
SortQuestions($answers, 5);

?>
```

Is there technique that I can use to shuffle the answers by the number passed into the function?

Comment: Would keeping the answer order inside a hidden input element be considered "storing"? :)

Answer (score 3):

PHP's [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) function uses the random seed given with [srand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php), so you can set a specific random seed for this.

Also, the shuffle method change's the array keys, but this is probably not the best outcome for you, so you may use a different shuffle function:

```
function shuffle_assoc(&$array, $random_seed) {
    srand($random_seed);

    $keys = array_keys($array);

    shuffle($keys);

    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $new[$key] = $array[$key];
    }

    $array = $new;

    return true;
}
```

This function will keep the original keys, but with a different order.

Comment: Unfortunately `srand` only works once per PHP process. If you call this function twice with the same seed you will get different results (even though you will get the *same* different results each time).

Comment: @mistermartin: I meant that subsequent `srand` calls after the first one would have no effect for the duration of the PHP process. Unfortunately I can't reproduce this today and I didn't provide any reference above, so it seems it's inaccurate. I will delete both these comments tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

You could rotate the array by a factor.

```
$factor = 5;
$numbers = array(1,2,3,4);
for ( $i = 0; $i < $factor; $i++ ) {
    array_push($numbers, array_shift($numbers));
}
print_r($numbers);
```

The factor can be randomized, and a function can switch the array back in place, by rotation the other way around.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  You define the `$factor` and don't make use of it within the code :/

Comment: That works well, but I just wish there was a way to make it a little more random?  Any ideas? :)

Comment: You could do a rotation pattern with randomly shifting random amounts left and right, however that does get a bit hairy, and requires you to store the pattern if you want to rebuild it. If you can't store the values it's gonna get really hard making it appear random

Answer (score 0):

This can be one of the possible ways.

```
$result = SortQuestions($answers, 30);
print_r($result);


function SortQuestions($answers, $num)
{
$answers = range(1, $num);
shuffle($answers);
return $answers;
}
```