# Make a random for an array with the same value

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3, php-5.5

I have this array

```
Array
(
[19] => Array
    (
        [nState] => -1
        [bActive] => 1
    )

[20] => Array
    (
        [nState] => -1
        [bActive] => 1
    )

[21] => Array
    (
        [nState] => -1
        [bActive] =>
    )
```

I want to make a random for this array but always get the same values. For example I want to get always the array with keys `12 11 13 10`. I searched on web but always the values are differents. Can you help me please ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: What does exactly mean `always`? The only way you can do this is to generate a random number, then save it somewhere (database or session depending on the needs), and use it later...

Comment: that doesn't look like an array... more like a json object. can you give an example of what you've tried, please?

Comment: @mistermartin done

Comment: @HareaCosticla does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376120/shuffling-array-in-the-same-way-according-to-number) help? Sounds like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this variant of `shuffle`:

```
function shuffled_seed($arr, $seed) {
    $len = count($arr);
    $shuffled = [];
    while ($len) {
        $shuffled[] = array_splice($arr, $seed % $len, 1)[0];
        $seed = floor($seed / $len);
        $len--;
    }
    return $shuffled;
}
```

If you provide twice the same arguments, you'll get twice the same return value. The second argument is the seed. You could for instance generate this as a random number the first time, but then remember it for any next time you need to reproduce the same array.

Example call:

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
$seed = rand();
$result = shuffled_seed($arr, $seed);
print_r($result);

$result = shuffled_seed($arr, $seed); // same seed
print_r($result); // same result
```

Comment: why are you building your own shuffle, instead of using the built-in one which uses `srand()` as a seed? it appears as though `srand($seed); shuffle($arr);` would be just as efficient.

Comment: The reason I did not refer to *srand* is that it will not work as expected on PHP installations that have the Suhosin patch installed. The use of *srand* is also tricky, since it behaves in unexpected ways when called more than once in the same session. See the comments section on [`srand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php).